# Emulate subquery with no main table in access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I can do this in `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT 'HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA' AS TIPO_PRODUCTO,
       0 AS DEPRECIACION,
       (select sum(empid) from HR.employees) STOCK
```

but in `Access` the same query show me the next error:

> Query input must contain at least one table or query

So which could be the best form to emulate this? Make a query with any other table looks dirty for me.

**EDIT 1:**, HR.employees It may no have data, but i want show constants ('HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA',''0') and 0 in the third column, maybe using isnull and this is not the problem here.

Comment: please tell what the question is unclear??. I need to emulate that query... this doesn't work in access... .

Answer (score 2):

Why not to select directly:

```
select 'HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA' AS TIPO_PRODUCTO,
        0 AS DEPRECIACION, 
        IIF(ISNULL(sum(empid)), 0, sum(empid)) AS STOCK 
from HR.employees
```

Comment: Because if no data in Hr.employees, it doesn't show any result, i will edit my question including an isnull, because i want a 0 if sum(empid) has no values.

Comment: thank you for edit and for try to help me, can you please take a look to my edit ?, if no data in HR.employees, no rows returned.

Comment: @JuanRuizdeCastilla, In my access database it does return a row when the table is empty! I don't know why you have a problem with that - it works for me...

Comment: you rigth when you say that your query return data, i will need to put my exact query because i was noticing and strange behavior in access, I will be free with my issues and continue with the review, thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Using this example as empty table:

```
with employ as
    (select 2 as col from dual
    minus
    select 2 as col from dual)
```

The query is this one:

```
select 'HERRAM' as tipo,
    0 as deprec,
    coalesce(sum(col), 0) as STOCK
from employ;
```

`coalesce(x, value)` sets the column to value when X is null

Comment: if employ table is empty, the query show 'HERRAM',0,0 ?... .

Comment: You're right! I've changed the query so that it doesn't have this issue

Answer (score 0):

This simply doesn't work in Access. You need a FROM clause.

So you need to have a dummy table with one record, even if you don't use a single field from that table.

```
SELECT 'HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA' AS TIPO_PRODUCTO,
       0 AS DEPRECIACION,
       (select sum(empid) from HR.employees) STOCK
FROM Dummy_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

In Access, you can use a system table, and `Val` and `Nz` for the zero value:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    'HERRAMIENTA ELÉCTRICA' AS TIPO_PRODUCTO,
    0 AS DEPRECIACION,
    Val(Nz((select sum(empid) from HR.employees), 0)) AS STOCK
FROM
    MSysObjects
```